# How to import "android.support.wearable.watchface" in Eclipse for Android Wear?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm doing my best to figure out how to develop apps in Eclipse for Android Wear (I really don't like Android Studio). I have made a couple of apps so far for Android Wear in Eclipse that work perfectly fine, but I'm running into a big problem when trying to create a Watch Face.

I can't import the following:

```
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.CanvasWatchFaceService;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceService;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceStyle;
```

I have added the wearable-1.0.0.aar as a library as discussed [here](https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d). I have tried adding as an external jar the "android-support-v7-appcomapt.jar" file located at "...sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs", but still no luck.

I am using the "Watchface" example given by google. When using it in Android Studio it works perfectly fine. The exact error I'm getting is:

```
CanvasWatchFaceService cannot be resolved to a type
```

Also, in my project under Android Private Libraries I have "classes.jar" and "android-support-v4.jar".

Does anyone have a fix? I figure it has something to do with external libraries and/or a jar I've missed.

Comment: do not tag `androidstudio` if it is not android studio related question. also like it or not, switch to android studio to save your time in future. eclipse is no longer actively supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. For anyone else who comes across this thread, the answer lies in the wearable-1.0.0 library in that it does not contain CanvasWatchFaceService. After looking through some of the other wearable projects, I found that the later versions have it. Just go to ...sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\support\wearable. I chose the wearable-1.4.0 version.

Also, I added the external jar "android-support-v7-palette.jar" from the Android tools folder.

Now everything works perfectly for me.